# Same distribution of two sequences

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables such that:
$$\mathbb P (X_n = 0) = \frac{1}{2} \text{ and } \mathbb P(X_n =1) = \frac{1}{2}$$

For all $n \geq 1$, let's define:

$S_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^{k-n-1}X_k$ and $T_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^{-k}X_k$.

Why do $S_n$ and $T_n$ have the same distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the change of indices $i = -(k-n-1)$, hence $k = n-i+1$, one gets $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n 2^{-i}X_{n-i+1}$. Now, the random vectors ${(X_k)}_{k=1}^n = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ and ${(X_{n-i+1})}_{i=1}^n = (X_n, \ldots, X_1)$ have the same distribution. Therefore $S_n$ and $T_n$ have the same distribution.